# No Update done with PDO php

Tags: php, pdo

I have problem without any error in my code that update row ..

```
if(!isset($error)){

    try {
        $sql = "UPDATE `invoice` SET `client`='".$client."', `company`='".$company."' , `clientemail`='".$clientemail."' , `mobailclient`='".$mobailclient."' , `startdate`='".$startdate."' , `enddate`='".$enddate."' WHERE `id` ='".$id."'";

        $count = $db->exec($sql);


        //redirect to invoice page
        header('Location: invoice.php');
        exit;

    //else catch the exception and show the error.
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        $error[] = $e->getMessage();
    }

}
```

This is my code , i try to get variable `$sql` and go to mysql phpmyadmin and its work good ,, but in file not work and i dont get any error

====  Update ====

i try this and not work

```
    try {
        $sql = 'UPDATE invoice SET client = :client,  company = :company,  clientemail = :clientemail,  mobailclient = :mobailclient,  startdate = :startdate,  enddate = :enddate WHERE id = :id';

        $statement = $db->prepare($sql);
        $statement->bindParam(":client", $client);
        $statement->bindParam(":company", $company); 
        $statement->bindParam(":clientemail", $clientemail); 
        $statement->bindParam(":mobailclient", $mobailclient); 
        $statement->bindParam(":startdate", $startdate); 
        $statement->bindParam(":enddate", $enddate); 
        $statement->bindParam(":id", intval($_GET['id']) ); 
        $statement->execute();
        if($statement->rowCount() > 0) // will return 1 if any row is updated
        {
            echo "<script>alert('".$statement->rowCount()."')</script>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<script>alert('No record updated')</script>";
        }
```

Comment: Do you enter in the if statement?

Comment: yes i enter ,, i put redirect to invoice page, and its redirect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is opened for SQL Injection. You should use parameterized query which provide a kind of protection against SQL injection but will not provide 100% of protection. Kindly visit this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection) for more details.

Try the following code by replacing table and column names.

```
$client = "my name";
$company = "my-company";
$id= 2;//make sure your table has a record with that specific id
$sql = 'UPDATE invoice SET client = :client,  company = :company WHERE id = :id'; // here i am updating only two columns
//You can add more column that you want to upate like ColumnName = :ParameterIdentifier
//Where ParameterIdentifier Is the name of parameter used in bindParam as in my example company  
$statement = $db->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindParam("client", $client); //Binding parameter for client
$statement->bindParam("company", $company); //Binding parameter for company 
$statement->bindParam("id", $id); 
$statement->execute();
if($statement->rowCount() > 0) // will return 1 if any row is updated
{
    echo "Record updated successfully";
}
else
{
    echo "No record updated";
}
```

Comment: what you mean for `$name` in `$statement->bindParam("LastName", $name);`

Comment: In my given sample I have set dummy variables. Just to provide you a hint. You can change according to your need

Comment: I have edited my answer and make a query that will update only two columns.

Comment: Do not pass values directly to bindParam() method

Comment: first assigned id to a variable then passed that variable to bindParam() method
Like:
$id = intval($_GET['id']);
$statement->bindParam(":id",$id  );

Comment: Glad to help you